# XML3D Bounding boxes

Tags: javascript, xml3d

From what I've read in specs each scene element form XML3D has bounding box associated with it.
I would like to ask how is the size of bounding boxes calculated?
Especially for the `<group>`
 and `<xml3d>` elements - does it take into consideration the sizes of children's bounding boxes?
I assume that bounding box size for `<mesh>` is calculated from mesh vertices positions.

I need this knowledge to tweak camera translation speed.

Comment: Ok I've checked it seems that xml3d bounding box is just set to be whole space. Which doesn;t make sense imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed on `<mesh>` elements it's calculated from the vertex positions. For `<group>` elements it's basically calculated as follows:

```
var bbox = new XML3DBox();
for (var child in children) {
    bbox.extend(child.getWorldBoundingBox());
}
```

So it recurses until it hits `<mesh>` elements and the resulting bounding box for each group in the hierarchy is the smallest volume that encloses the bounding boxes of all the child elements, whether they be `<groups>` or `<meshes>`. A `<group>` with no renderable objects (`<mesh>` or `<model>`) anywhere in its subtree will return an empty box.

On the `<xml3d>` element it will return a box that encloses the entire scene.

One thing to remember is that objects marked as invisible (with the visible="false" attribute) won't be included in the bounding box calculations.